# how to bind a jframe class to my all other classes?? Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, bind

I created a GUI using NetBeans. Inside the GUI I have 2 textfield, 1 for username and 1 for password, and a button "Login".

The username and password properties (login method too) are inside another class, here's the class:

```
    public class SelexiaBot implements Serializable {  
    public String username, password;
    public Login log = null;

    public SelexiaBot(){}

    public void getLogin(){
        if(robot != null){
            if(driver != null){
                if(user != null){
                    if(pass != null){
                        if(server != null){
                            this.log = new Login(robot, driver, user, pass, server, url);
                            log.login();
                        }else System.out.println("Type your server");
                    }else System.out.println("Type your password");
                }else System.out.println("Type your username");
            }else System.out.println("Error driver");
        }else System.out.println("Error robot");
    }

    public void setUser(String user){
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setPassword(String pass){
        this.pass = pass;
    }
}
```

The question is, how do I bind textfields and the button to this other class?

This is the GUI source:

```
    public class Home {

    private JFrame frmOgameSelexiabot;
    private JTextField txtUsername;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Home window = new Home();
                    window.frmOgameSelexiabot.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Home() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmOgameSelexiabot = new JFrame();
        frmOgameSelexiabot.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Home.class.getResource("/icon.png")));
        frmOgameSelexiabot.setTitle("OGame SelexiaBot");
        frmOgameSelexiabot.setBounds(100, 100, 624, 494);
        frmOgameSelexiabot.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frmOgameSelexiabot.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);
        frmOgameSelexiabot.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        Label label = new Label("Username:");
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 56, 22);
        frmOgameSelexiabot.getContentPane().add(label);

        txtUsername = new JTextField();
        txtUsername.setBounds(62, 0, 67, 20);
        frmOgameSelexiabot.getContentPane().add(txtUsername);
        txtUsername.setColumns(10);

        Label label_1 = new Label("Password:");
        label_1.setBounds(135, 0, 62, 22);
        frmOgameSelexiabot.getContentPane().add(label_1);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(203, 0, 67, 20);
        frmOgameSelexiabot.getContentPane().add(passwordField);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.setBounds(419, 0, 89, 23);
        frmOgameSelexiabot.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post [mcve]. It is impossible to help you with the posted code. For example `Login robot driver  user pass server url` are not defined

Comment: Please define 'bind'. And note the [tag:bind] tag wiki: 'This tag means different things in different contexts; consider using less ambiguous tags instead or in addition. Common meanings include: the bind method in jQuery; the bind function in socket programming. For boost::bind in C++, use [boost-bind]. Do not use this tag just to say that you're binding something to something else.'

Comment: @EJP for "binding" I mean that I'd like to call the method log.login(); (Inside the Login public class) by clicking the button in the GUI "Login".
Also textfields username and password in the GUI should initialize the variables "username" and "password" inside the "Login" public class.

Comment: @c0der yes sorry, in the entire class them are defined, but I cut off some parts of the code because it was the oppost of minimal ;)

Comment: It is suppose to be minimal and comilable